# How to get the sum of a column based on a distinct key (different column)

Tags: mysql, sql, vertica

I wanted to know how to get the distinct sum of products

The table I have

```
Name Rating
 A     3
 A     3
 B     4
 C     3
 C     3
```

The final result I want is 
`SUM(case when distinct table1.name then rating)/Count(case when distinct table1.name then rating)`

final answer = (3+4+3)/3 = 10/3 = 3.33

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why is your question tagged Vertica & MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an other perspective.

Find average rating for each Name and then average of grouped.

**Query**

```
select avg(t.`avg`) as `avg` from
(
  select Name,
  avg(rating) as `avg`
  from your_table_name
  group by Name
)t;
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2db40/2)

Comment: This another perspective it totally broken. Example  **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374729)**. Average for averages is not the same as Average of set of data. In your specific example where all data inside group are the same it works, but when you have different values it will fail for example (A,3), (A,1).

Comment: @lad2025: It should be 3.1111 right in the sample created.

Comment: Let's calculate (3 + 4 + 3 + 1) / 4 = 2.75

Answer (score 0):

`SUM/COUNT` <=> `AVG` so

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/513d9/2/0)**

```
SELECT (SUM(Rating) * 1.0)/COUNT(*)  AS result
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM tab
  ) AS sub;
```

can be:

**[SqlFiddleDemo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/513d9/3/0)**

```
SELECT AVG(Rating)  AS result
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM tab
  ) AS sub;
```